# Adding a shipping Address to a guest cart in Magento

Tags: magento2, magento-ee

I am trying to add a shipping address to a guest cart in magento but it's throwing the following error.

```
POST: http://staging.yudala.com/ee/rest/V1/guest-carts/0faff9e835d1ca9c84d7526ee288398f/shipping-information

{
  "message": "Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2",
  "parameters": [
    null,
    null
  ],
}
```

here is my payload:

```
{
   "addressInformation": {
      "shippingAddress": {
         "city": "Nigeria",
         "country_id": "NG",
         "firstname": "someone",
         "lastname": "something",
         "postcode": "11756",
         "region_code": "LG",
         "street": [
            "address01",
            "address02"
         ],
         "telephone": "1111111111"
      }
   }
}
```

Please am I missing out something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're missing things.Your parameters are not correct.Use this format:

```
{"addressInformation":
  {"shipping_address": 
    {"countryId":"NG",
    "regionId":"508",
  "regionCode":"Kebbi",
   "region":"Kebbi",
   "street": [0:"",1:""],
   "postcode":"234",
   "city":"Lagos"},
"billing_address": 
 {"countryId":"NG",
"regionId":"508",
"regionCode":"Kebbi",
"region":"Kebbi",
"street":[0:"Lagos"],
"company":"Yudala","telephone":"","postcode":"234","city":"Uyo",
"firstname":"Kpono",
"lastname":"Akpabio",
"saveInAddressBook":false},
"shipping_method_code":"yucarrier",
"shipping_carrier_code":"yucarrier"}}
```